# MongoDB pagination

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying to implement MongoDB pagination based on a query which always should short by a date field named `updateTime`.

I tried to implement pagination paging by a next and previous `ObjectID` using the operators `$gt` and `$lt` and limiting by some results page size.

In adition the query may include multiple filters (distinc field matching values).

In order to build a consistent pagination approach, based on the query which may include or not filters, I try to determine the first and last ObjectID despite of the numbers of pages a search might generate.

```
@staticmethod
def paginate_reviews(gt_oid, lt_oid, account, location, rating, responded, start_datetime=None, end_datetime=None):
    query = {'location': {'$in': location}}
    if account is not None:
        query['account'] = account
    if start_datetime is not None and end_datetime is not None:
        query['updateTime'] = {'$gte': start_datetime, '$lte': end_datetime}
    if gt_oid is not None:
        query['_id'] = {'$gt': ObjectId(gt_oid)}
    elif lt_oid is not None:
        query['_id'] = {'$lt': ObjectId(lt_oid)}
    if rating is not None and len(rating) is not 0:
        rating = [int(r) for r in rating]
        query['starRatingNumber'] = {'$in': rating}
    if responded is not None:
        responded = json.loads(responded)
        query['reviewReply'] = {'$exists': responded}

    reviews = Review.objects.filter(__raw__=query).order_by('-updateTime', '_id')[:25]
    response = {
        'reviews': reviews
    }

    if gt_oid is None and lt_oid is None:
        first = Review.objects().filter(__raw__=query).order_by('updateTime').first()
        last = Review.objects().filter(__raw__=query).order_by('-updateTime').first()
        first_oid = str(first.to_mongo().get('_id')) if first is not None else None
        last_oid = str(last.to_mongo().get('_id')) if last is not None else None
        response['first_oid'] = first_oid
        response['last_oid'] = last_oid

    return response
```

Where `first_oid` is supposed to be the first document of first page and `last_oid` should be the last element of last page.

When I'm at first page, I query a next one like this:

`db.review.find({"_id" : {$gt: ObjectId("5a776c41c68932281c2240f1")}}).sort({'_id': 1, 'updateTime': -1}).limit(25)`

Being `5a776c41c68932281c2240f1` the last element of first page.

So far, it's working properly when trying to paginate forward. However when trying to paginate backwards something weird happens as even I'm in a 3rd, 5th or whatever page, a match using `$lt` passing the first element in a page is returning first element of page 1.

This is breaking my whole implementation. How should I adjust it?

Comment: Do you reverse the sort order when going backwards? If you don't you'll get the start of the collection every time.

Comment: @IanMercer not really, everything I'm doing is what I've shared in the code snippet in my question

Comment: Well if you `order_by('-updateTime', '_id')` when trying to go backwards you will always get the first 25 instead of the last 25 that are before the _id you are seeking surely??? Shouldn't you order by the reverse order when going backward, grab 25 and then reverse them in memory?